# Why CGPath and UIBezierPath define "clockwise" differently in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, cgpath

In SpriteKit, the `clockwise` direction is reversed for `UIBezierPath` but not for `CGPath`. For example, if I have

```
do {
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 0, 10, 0, CGFloat(M_PI_2), true)
    let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    node.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(node)
}
do {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 10, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: true)
    let node = SKShapeNode(path: path.CGPath)
    node.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2 - 100)
    self.addChild(node)
}
```

in `GameScene.didMoveToView(view: SKView)`, the first node draws a 3/4 arc with top-right missing, but the second node draws a quarter arc at top-right. The reversed "clockwise" direction in `UIBezierPath` is explained [in this post](http://www.simosh.com/article/dggggjha-circle-from-uibezierpath-drawn-in-wrong-direction-in-skshapenode.html), but why doesn't `CGPath` behave the same? Isn't `UIBezierPath` just a wrapper around `CGPath`?

Note: This happens to both Objective-C and Swift (so not language-specific). Did not try on Mac App with `NSBezierPath`.

Comment: I first read "Do not try on Mac App with NSBezierPath!", like it would be somehow dangerous 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CGPath` and `UIBezierPath` use different coordinate systems. `UIBezierPath`'s origin is at the top-left corner of the drawing area and `CGPath`'s origin in at the bottom-left. Consequently, 90º is the lowest point on the circle for `UIBezierPath` and the highest point for `CGPath`. Since 0º is at the same point (right-most point) on the circle for both paths, the resulting clockwise arcs from 0º to 90º are drawn differently.

With the origin at the top-left, 90º (π/2) is at the lowest point on the circle and, therefore, a clockwise `UIBezierPath` arc is drawn as shown in the figure below. Since SpriteKit's origin is at the bottom-left, this arc appears flipped (vertically) when used to create the `SKShapeNode`.

[image]

With the origin at the bottom-left, 90º is at the top of the circle and a clockwise `CGPath` arc is drawn as shown below. Since SpriteKit's origin is also at the bottom-left, the shape node arc appears in the same orientation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just found the reference about this for [`UIBezierView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW5) and [`CGPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC).

Comment: "Since SpriteKit's origin is at the bottom-left, this arc appears flipped (vertically) when used to create the SKShapeNode."
I'm surprised this isn't more visibly documented. A vertical flip is literally the difference between clockwise and counterclockwise and I've been tearing my hair out wondering why my UIBezierCurve was coming out counterclockwise through my SKShapeNode.